# IIS - Redirect http requests from url to another url in the same folder

Tags: iis

I have an asp page as part of of web application hosted on IIS8. I would like to set up http redirection from this page to another aspx page within the same site.Isn't there a straightforward setting I can use in IIS? I've looked at http redirect and url rewrite with little luck.

Requests to

```
http://localhost/example.asp
```

needs to be redirected to

```
http://localhost/example.aspx
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. I was missing the URL Rewrite module.It can be downloaded [here](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite).Once you download, install the url rewrite module and it will look like this.Open the feature and add the rule.

[image]

Once you add a new rule it will show up in the web.config file under system.webserver tags or you can add it to the web.config file directly.

```
<system.webServer>
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="asp_to_aspx" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^example.asp$" />
            <action type="Redirect" url="http://localhost/example.aspx" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```